# Manifest for PWA with scope bind to sub-folder

Tags: progressive-web-apps, manifest, workbox

Lets say, a PWA is deployed to a sub-directory of a regular website (e.g. `https://example.net/app`). It uses hash-mode for its navigation (e.g. `/app/#/login` and `/app/#/dashboard`).

Now, there are links inside this PWA which leading to the website, e.g. `https://example.net/product-list`. This link should leave the PWA and open the native default browser of a mobile device.

Therefore we set the scope of our manifest.json to `"scope": "https://example.net/app"`, because [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/scope#examples) say, that everything what leaves the sub-directory should be treated as "outside of scope":

```
Finally, the following example limits navigation to a subdirectory of the current site:
"scope": "https://example.com/subdirectory/"
```

Unfortunately that does not work, neither on iOS nor on Android: all links of that domain are is still opened inside the PWAs webview! In detail:

- Click on `https://example.net/app/#/login` from a different app (e.g Whatsapp or Slack): expected to open in PWA => that works
- Click on `https://example.net/product-list` from a different app (e.g Whatsapp or Slack): expected to open in default browser, but opens in PWA webview => thats's wrong!
- Click on `https://example.net/product-list` from inside PWA: expected to open in default browser, but opens in same PWA webview => thats's wrong!

What can be the issue here? From our understanding a request to `https://example.net/product-list` clearly is outside of a scope binded to `https://example.net/app`

Highly appreciate any clarification on that matter.

PS: also looked into the standard description [here](https://w3c.github.io/manifest/), section "Understanding scope", but it is not clearer.

**Edit:**
Setting the scope to `https://app.example.net/` and serve it from that sub-domain is not an option.